# Google.Apis.Calendar.v3 Clear Issue

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-calendar-api

Got this issue while trying to clear the events for primary calendar ID.

This issue occurred with my first_account@gmail.com account, But with my another account second_account@gmail.com , clear event works.

can anyone please help me with this ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Probable root cause could be heavy network traffic. Since you are just testing, you can try again until you get a success response.

If you will encounter this during the development stage suggested action for this error is to use [exponential backoff](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/push#responding-to-notifications).

> Exponential backoff is a standard error handling strategy for network
>   applications in which the client periodically retries a failed request
>   over an increasing amount of time. If a high volume of requests or
>   heavy network traffic causes the server to return errors, exponential
>   backoff may be a good strategy for handling those errors. Conversely,
>   it is not a relevant strategy for dealing with errors unrelated to
>   rate-limiting, network volume or response times, such as invalid
>   authorization credentials or file not found errors.
>
> Used properly, exponential backoff increases the efficiency of
>   bandwidth usage, reduces the number of requests required to get a
>   successful response, and maximizes the throughput of requests in
>   concurrent environments.
>
> Create requests are not idempotent. A simple retry is insufficient and
>   may result in duplicate entities. Check whether the entity exists
>   before retrying.